# Finding icon-names for Web Component lightning cards

Tags: html, lightning-web-components, svg-icon

In an example of creating a lightning web component, the html used a `lightning-card` tag. Within that tag, it declared a `title` and `icon-name`, where the `icon` pointed to `custom:custom19`

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="My Title" icon-name="custom:custom19">
    // Rest of html
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Where in salesforce can I find all the `custom:customXX` icons so that I don't have to use the one in the example?

Answer (score 7):

In the salesforce lightning design system docs [here](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/)